# Windows 11 detecting wrong resolution and refresh rate

Tags: windows, video, hdmi, resolution, refresh-rate

I have an acer predator PH315-53-75N8 and bought a M27Q Gigabyte monitor, which is a 2k 165Hz monitor. When connected via HDMI 2.0 cable, windows is saying the recommended resolution is 4k and refresh rate cannot go further than 60Hz. I can switch to 2k resolution but it gets blurry and i also cannot go further than 60Hz.

I also use the monitor on my desktop and it works perfectly. Not blurry 2k as recommended and 165Hz.

Comment: If you'd like help please edit your question to include the full part number for the laptop as there are multiple variants of the acer predator PH315-53

Comment: Edited with the correct version

Comment: Are you running these tests with the laptop display disabled?  Have you tried the Display Port (might be mini-dp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was to reinstall the nvidia driver with a clean installation through the customized installation option.